# Generating a list of service accounts on a system

Tags: bash, scripting

For a forensics competition I need to generate a list of service accounts present on a system. My idea at the moment is to used the SYS_UID_MIN and SYS_UID_MAX parameters located in /etc/login.defs and then grep for all values within the range.

However, I don't know how to prevent usernames from being matched as well. Is there a way to only grep on the second column?

Here's the code I have right now:

```
sudo -v
sysmin=$(grep ^SYS_UID_MIN /etc/login.defs | awk '{print $2}')
sysmax=$(grep ^SYS_UID_MAX /etc/login.defs | awk '{print $2}')
awk -F: '{printf $1, printf " ", print $3}' /etc/passwd | grep /[$sysmin-$sysmax]/ > sysuserslist.temp
```

Comment: `awk -vmin=$sysmin -vmax=$sysmax -F: '$2 > min && $2 < max { print $1, $3 }'` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` to remove everything but the 2nd column so `grep` won't match on usernames.

```
cut -d 'delimiter' -f 2
```

Would return the second field delimited by 'delimiter'. Default delimiter is TAB.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut